# Multiple graphs in real time with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python3 and my task is to receive multiple signals from different sensors and graph them. I already managed to graph the signals in real-time and also use the subplot (), subplots () functions but the problem is that all the signals come out on a single graph and I need each signal to have its own graph.
ps: I've already used threads for each signal but the subsequent threads kill the process of the previous thread.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

def animate(num,hl,listax,listay,hl2=None,listax2=None,listay2=None):
    plt.xlim(listax[0],listax[-1])
    xs = np.array(listax)
    ys = np.array(listay)
    hl.set_data(xs,ys)
    if hl2 != None:
        #plt.xlim(listax[0],listax[-1])
        xs2 = np.array(listax2)
        ys2 = np.array(listay2)
        hl2.set_data(xs2,ys2)
        return hl , hl2
    else:   
        return hl,

def main(time,signal,signal2):

     fig , (hl,hl2)= plt.subplots(2,1)
     hl, = plt.plot(time,signal)
     hl2, = plt.plot(time,signal2)
     ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,fargs=(hl,time,signal,hl2,time,signal2),interval=1,blit=False)
     plt.show()

main(time,signal,signal2)
#time is the list of  time when the measures were taken
#Signal,signal2 are lists of the measures taken on those times
#those lists are in constant upgrade mode trough a thread that upgrades those lists
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I only got the graphs animation in the last graph.

Answer (score 1):

Made a sample according to [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html) and your code. Note `frame` is used for animation one-shot, but in code frame is defined as list (range(len(time)). If you want to set axis limit initially, use init parameter of FuncAnimation. (In case you are using Jupyter... on Jupyter animation don't wokk, please call py from terminal etc..)

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def update(frame):
    xdata.append(time[frame])
    ydata.append(signal[frame])
    ydata2.append(signal2[frame])
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    ln2.set_data(xdata, ydata2)
    return ln, ln2


time = range(0, 10)
signal = range(10, 20)
signal2 = range(50, 60)

frame = range(len(time))

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)

ln, = ax.plot([], [], "o")
ln2, = ax2.plot([], [], "ro")

xdata = []
ydata = []
ydata2 = []

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frame, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: How about plotting without animation, is that working?